# "ambiguous statement error" while using jexl3 expression with variable names in Concurrency Thread Group

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

**Note: Even though there are errors in the log, script gets executed as inteded. I am trying to understand how to remove these errors which are flooding logs**

I am using JMeter 5.3 and setting up a Concurrency thread group with Throughput Shaping Timer.

Now the Throughput Shaping Timer works as intended however when I use Variable names in the Configuration, logs get flooded with jexl3 errors. Below are the details of the Configuration that I am using:
[image]

**Thread Group:**

[image]

When I use the variable names in the ramp up period, I consistently get following error in the logs

```
    2021-05-17 19:13:49,454 ERROR o.a.j.f.Jexl3Function: An error occurred while evaluating the expression "${RampUpPeriod}/60"

org.apache.commons.jexl3.JexlException$Ambiguous: 60@1:17 ambiguous statement error in '${RampUpPeriod}/60'
    at org.apache.commons.jexl3.parser.JexlParser.throwParsingException(JexlParser.java:270) ~[commons-jexl3-3.1.jar:3.1]
    at org.apache.commons.jexl3.parser.JexlParser.jjtreeCloseNodeScope(JexlParser.java:207) ~[commons-jexl3-3.1.jar:3.1]
    at org.apache.commons.jexl3.parser.Parser.ExpressionStatement(Parser.java:505) ~[commons-jexl3-3.1.jar:3.1]
    at org.apache.commons.jexl3.parser.Parser.Statement(Parser.java:350) ~[commons-jexl3-3.1.jar:3.1]
    at org.apache.commons.jexl3.parser.Parser.JexlScript(Parser.java:93) ~[commons-jexl3-3.1.jar:3.1]
    at org.apache.commons.jexl3.parser.Parser.parse(Parser.java:25) ~[commons-jexl3-3.1.jar:3.1]
    at org.apache.commons.jexl3.internal.Engine.parse(Engine.java:594) ~[commons-jexl3-3.1.jar:3.1]
    at org.apache.commons.jexl3.internal.Engine.createScript(Engine.java:261) ~[commons-jexl3-3.1.jar:3.1]
    at org.apache.commons.jexl3.internal.Engine.createScript(Engine.java:58) ~[commons-jexl3-3.1.jar:3.1]
    at org.apache.commons.jexl3.JexlEngine.createScript(JexlEngine.java:316) ~[commons-jexl3-3.1.jar:3.1]
    at org.apache.jmeter.functions.Jexl3Function.execute(Jexl3Function.java:96) ~[ApacheJMeter_functions.jar:5.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.engine.util.CompoundVariable.execute(CompoundVariable.java:135) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.3]
    at org.apache.jmeter.engine.util.CompoundVariable.execute(CompoundVariable.java:110) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.3]
    at kg.apc.jmeter.JMeterVariableEvaluator.evaluate(JMeterVariableEvaluator.java:9) ~[jmeter-plugins-cmn-jmeter-0.6.jar:?]
    at com.blazemeter.jmeter.threads.LoadParamsFieldsPanel.UItoModel(LoadParamsFieldsPanel.java:45) ~[jmeter-plugins-casutg-2.9.jar:?]
    at com.blazemeter.jmeter.threads.AbstractDynamicThreadGroupGui.updateUI(AbstractDynamicThreadGroupGui.java:139) ~[jmeter-plugins-casutg-2.9.jar:?]
    at com.blazemeter.jmeter.threads.AbstractDynamicThreadGroupGui.run(AbstractDynamicThreadGroupGui.java:113) ~[jmeter-plugins-casutg-2.9.jar:?]
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:316) ~[?:?]
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:770) ~[?:?]
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721) ~[?:?]
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715) ~[?:?]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391) [?:?]
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85) [?:?]
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:740) [?:?]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203) [?:?]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124) [?:?]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113) [?:?]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109) [?:?]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101) [?:?]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90) [?:?]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like a bug in the plugin, you can try reaching out to JMeter Plugins developers and maintainers via [JMeter Plugins Support Forum](https://groups.google.com/g/jmeter-plugins). If you're a BlazeMeter customer you can [open a BlazeMeter support ticket](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207491229-How-to-Open-a-Support-Ticket-How-to-Open-a-Support-Ticket)

In the meantime you can work it around by adding another [User Defined Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#User_Defined_Variables) configuration element below your original one and put your calculation logic there:

[image]

once done you can replace the __jexl3() functions in the Concurrency Thread Group with the calculated variables:

[image]